# How to get value of 'select' type instead of labels on button submit in form io for default set value?

Tags: select, formio

Successfully rendered form using `form-io`. And I have `select` fields with `defaultValue` as,

```
{
                    "authenticate": false,
                    "hidden": false,
                    "data": {
                        "values": [{
                            "label": "New",
                            "value": 1
                        }, {
                            "label": "In Progress",
                            "value": 2
                        }, {
                            "label": "Resolved",
                            "value": 3
                        }, {
                            "label": "Feedback",
                            "value": 4
                        }, {
                            "label": "Closed",
                            "value": 5
                        }, {
                            "label": "Rejected",
                            "value": 6
                        }]
                    },
                    "defaultValue": "New",
                    "multiple": false,
                    "labelMargin": 3,
                    "tableView": true,
                    "clearOnHide": true,
                    "labelWidth": 30,
                    "label": "Status",
                    "autofocus": false,
                    "type": "select",
                    "input": true,
                    "protected": false,
                    "labelPosition": "left-right",
                    "unique": false,
                    "persistent": true,
                    "key": "ticket_status",
                    "dataSrc": "values",
                    "validate": {
                        "required": true
                    }
                }
```

and on button click I have to get those `value`. Now I am getting the `labels` for `default set options`, not `value`.On `submit` button click am doing as follows,

```
Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), data,{
                                readOnly: false
                            }).then(function(form) {
                                  form.on('submit', function(event) {                            
                                 that.savingNewTicket(event.data);
                                });
                            });
```

but when I select any other option the `value` is getting on submit but for `defaultValue` set option I am getting those `labels` not `value`. How can I get `value`??

Answer (score 0):

Gave `value` against `defaultValue`, then it worked.